# C# .net chart control catching error when unsuitable series is used

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

I have populated a combobox with a SeriesChartType list.  This allows the user to select which chart type the want to see.  This works well.
However, when there is more than one series, or if there are a different number of datapoints some chart types throw an exception.

> eg. System.InvalidOperationException: 'Renko chart type - Cannot
>   combine this chart type with any other charts.'

The hard part is that I cannot seem to catch the exception.  It gets thrown when i try to update the chart so I tried the following:

```
        try
        {
            Series1.ChartType = (SeriesChartType)Cmb_Select_Chart.SelectedItem;
            Chart.Update();
        }
        catch
        {
            foreach(Series x in Chart.Series)
            {
                x.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                MessageBox.Show("Error generating chart. Default to line.");
            }
        }
```

However, the try/catch doesn't work, it just throws the exception anyway. -Throws on Chart.update()

I would like to know how to catch or even just check for the error.
It would be nice to not have to chop and change the combobox list.

Can anyone shed any light on why this exception is not being caught in the try/catch block?
Thanks.

also attached below is what is hopefully the stack trace(still new never used it before)
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll!System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) Unknown No symbols loaded.
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e, short layer)    Unknown No symbols loaded.
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown No symbols loaded.
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
    [Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
    [Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Update()  Unknown No symbols loaded.

> Labassist.exe!Labassist.Frm_Charts.Populate_Chart() Line 404    C#  Symbols loaded.
>       Labassist.exe!Labassist.Frm_Charts.Cmb_Select_Chart_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 435    C#  Symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(System.EventArgs e)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       [Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
>       [Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(System.IntPtr hWnd, ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       [Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
>       [Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       [Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
>       [Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.DefChildWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ChildWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ComboBoxChildNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       [Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
>       [Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData)  Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context)    Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm)   Unknown No symbols loaded.
>       Labassist.exe!Labassist.Program.Main() Line 20  C#  Symbols loaded.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I can't get the exception to be caught either. It always terminates no matter where I attempt to catch it at. There also seems to be no way to detect before hand whether you can safely switch between chart types.

Comment: I had no luck solving it.  I just ended up manually creating a list of chart types that would not crash the program.

Comment: Still no answers for this problem ? I'm facing the exact same issue